# C - Reading parts of a file

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I have a file where each line has the following format: `%s %f %f \n.
Example:

- Arctic_fox 44.5 3.385
- Beaver 15.499 11.2

I want to skip the name of the animals and just get the float values after that. How can I do this?

Comment: Just read the strings into a dummy variable.

Comment: Basically i am doing a linear regression so i dont want strings in that, just the float.

Comment: You just throw the strings away after reading, what's the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Just read all data with `fscanf(f, "%s %f %f", str, &x, &y);` but do not use `str`. Or better use `fscanf(f, "%*s %f %f", &x, &y);`

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a C program for this.
Import the file in question to excel and remove the first column [which is the names of animals]. This will leave you with what you want.

Now you can save this file from excel.

Comment: Or you can hire somebody to do it by hand in a text editor...  You seem to be missing the point of automating tasks with programs.

Comment: Your comments are not very professional. There are occasions where we need to process a file just once. I was approaching the problem from that point.

Comment: The OP was asking about how to skip a field when parsing a file to perform some computations, petrovich answered promptly and precisely.  Your late answer is not helpful at all.  I will concede my comment was a bit sarcastic, but your answer sounded misplaced too.  On occasions where you need to process a file just once, a solution involving a simple one liner from the command line seems more in line with a programmer's approach.

Comment: We have no evidence that the first answer is helpful yet. So there is room for further suggestions. The question never mentioned that it needs to be done programatically, requirement was to get the number values. Now if the string is not null terminated, What's go a happen? Program will have to explicitly look for numbers.

Comment: loco's comment is evidence to me.  I'm not sure what you mean by *if the string is not null terminated*.  `fscanf` is not the right tool if the string contains embedded spaces.